# AG-Grid CSS syntax

Tags: css, ag-grid

I'm having problems understanding the AG-grid css syntax ([Variable Reference](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/global-style-customisation-variables/)).

disclaimer - I'm not a developer, just self-taught hobbiest, so I'm not sure what to search for.

I want to create my own theme for a project, and I wasn't getting anywhere, so I copied the css file for an existing theme, and intended to modify it to suit my needs, but I don't understand why its not working.

Below is an example (heavily truncated):

```
.ag-theme-pz {
...
--ag-background-color: rgba(209,210,210,0.75);   <-- Doesn't work
background-color: rgba(209,210,210,0.75);        <-- Does work
...
}
```

For some reason, in my copied css file, the syntax (--ag-background-color) no longer works - but it worked fine in the original css file.

Is there a reference I need to add to make sure the syntax as per their documentation works??

What have I missed?

Comment: Is there any chance you could create a sample in StackBlitz?  It makes it easier to look at the problem

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem but maybe this will be a helpful clue: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/global-style-customisation says, 

"CSS Variable support was added in v28 - if you have upgraded from an earlier version without changing your import paths then you will be using the legacy styles and will not have full CSS variable support. See the notes on upgrading to v28+."